# How to quit a job after 9 months of working there?

Tags: resignation

I want to quit my job as a data analyst because I decided to go back to school to pursue my masters in math education, and change my career path to teaching. However, I had a check in meeting with my bosses and they want me to take over a co worker’s position (who is leaving soon) and also keep my position. They kept pressuring me and convincing to do that role and I didn’t know how to respond. So I gave in.

So they want to train me in that role that my co worker did previously. However, I want to quit in two weeks but we are going to be short on staff. I’ve been at the company for 9 months.  How do I quit or what should I do?

Comment: Take charge over the path you want to persue and don't worry too much about their persistence in pressuring you to stay. They will find someone else and everone will move on..

Comment: Think about this:  If they were firing you, would you pressuring them to keep you on make any difference?

Comment: How is this different to any of the dozens of other "how do I quit?" questions on this site?

Comment: “but we are going to be short on staff” - You have it wrong; Once you put in your notice it’s **they** not “we” will be shorthanded.  They being shorthand will no longer be your problem. They will be able to replace you, just like they replaced your co-worker, by pressuring you to do their work…

Answer (score 14):

> How do I quit ?

You hand in your formal resignation in accordance with the rules of your contract & local laws. Typically you schedule a meeting with your manager, tell them that you are resigning and hand them a letter stating the same (including your last day of work)

> what should I do?

Resign. Do what you want to do.

> they kept pressuring me and convincing to do that role

Just ignore them. Sit in the meeting, listen politely and say as little as possible. Stick with "sorry, I have made my decision".

Comment: Good answer - one thing I'd suggest is being careful when saying "sorry." Depending on how you phrase it, saying sorry can imply that you're wrong, and give them more leverage against you. By all means, if you want, say that you're sorry that it's inconvenient for them, but I wouldn't say anything like "I'm sorry for causing you trouble."

Comment: It doesn't give them any leverage. They have no leverage. "I quit" does not have as a possible response "no you don't". There is no possible leverage whether you say the word "sorry" or not.

Answer (score 5):

Don't overthink it, each side has to worry about its own interests. With inverted roles, the company would have no problems in letting you go if they had the need, regardless of what commitment you might have taken.

Just hand in your resignation letter and serve the notice period as detailed in your contract.

In one of my previous jobs I started as an external consultant, and after 6 months in that arrangement they decided to give me a fixed position. Two weeks after signing the contract I decided to move to a different country and pursue my career there, so I just wrote a resignation letter, handed it to my manager, served the notice period (I could have quit with no notice since I was still in the probation period, but decided to serve 2 weeks to allow a smooth transition) and left.

If you want to explain why you are leaving the job, don't let it be a negotiation point, unless that is what you want.